# Monitor "Input not support"

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

Before Windows loads and the login screen appears, the message "Input not support" hangs on the screen. That is, I do not see the logo of the motherboard manufacturer, I cannot get into the BIOS when I turn on the PC, and I do not see the system boot. The image appears only when you need to enter the password. If you restart the computer, then everything is in order and this error does not exist, only if you turn it off and on. I tried to reset BIOS, CMOS and reinstalled windows, nothing helps. Previously, everything worked correctly, I can not remember anything what I could have done to provoke this problem.

- CPU: Intel Core i5 10400f
- GPU: GIGABYTE NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 4GB
- Mother board: Asus Prime B560m-a
- RAM: 2x8gb G.Skill Aegis 3200mHz
- OC: Windows 10 x64 Pro
- Monitor #1: AOC G2590PX 1920x1080p 144Hz DisplayPort
- Monitor #2: Samsung SyncMaster 2333 1920x1080p 60Hz VGA to DVI

Comment: The Q&As in the "Related" section on the right side of this page might help.

Comment: Your system possibly has an onboard video chip too, and the BIOS part is displayed through that GPU. So its an assumption, that if you power down the system, connect a display to that port and power it on, you can access the BIOS. Once there, you likely have a setting to switch to the dedicated GPU to fix the issue. Note, a restart with fast startup is different than a complete power down.